# Select condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**page1.php**

```
  echo '<form action="page2.php" name="myform"><table>
        <tr><td>name:<input type="text" name="n"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Choose Desc<select name="desc" value="0">
                  $descriptions = mysql_query('SELECT desc FROM desc_table');
                  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($descriptions))
                  {
                     $des = $row['desc'];
                     echo '<option>'.$des.'</option>';
                  }
                  </select>
       </td></tr>';
          <tr><td>Description:<textarea rows="10" cols="10" name="desc" value="1"></textarea></td>  </tr>     
 <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
 </table>
  </form>';
```

**Page2.php**

```
 $n = $_POST['n'];
 $desc = $_POST['desc'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO new (name,desc)
                VALUES ($n,$desc)";
 mysql_query($sql);
```

I need to store either one description either by selecting the description or typing the description in the textarea, but only one description should get stored to database.

Comment: Can you explain what **reason** is

Comment: Sorry it was description

Comment: How come there s no action in form ?

Comment: Sorry that was an typing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Change into this:

```
$n = $_REQUEST['n'];
$desc = $_REQUEST['desc'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO new (name,desc)
            VALUES ("$n","$desc")";
mysql_query($sql);
```

And add a method to your  tag

```
<FORM action="resultscript.php" method="POST"></FORM>
```

And try again ;-)

BTW: If the variables you are putting in your SQL might contain strings, you need to put them in double quotes (")

Comment: Could you see the database above image - It was stroing empty data to description column when i select

Comment: Instead of this: mysql_query($sql); do this: echo $sql; and post the results. It may bring some light on the problem...

Comment: INSERT INTO new(name,desc) VALUES (dfhdf,,) - this was showing wen I echo i.e., it wasn't showing the desc I selected

Comment: It is inserting the value from the Textbox, not from the dropdown, since they both have the same name, it is using the last one (the dropdown in this case). Give them both a different name, and check in your second script which one of both is selected. Then use the value of that one in your SQL.

Comment: Ya exactly, need help with the check script

Comment: if (isset($_REQUEST['descdrop']) && $_REQUEST['descdrop'] != "") { $des = $_REQUEST['descdrop']}elseif (isset($_REQUEST['desctype']) && $_REQUEST['desctype'] != "") { $des = $_REQUEST['desctype']}

Answer (score 2):

Your form was badly messed up:

```
<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>name:<input type="text" name="n"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose Desc
                <select name="desc" value="0">
                  <?php
                  $descriptions = mysql_query('SELECT desc FROM desc_table');
                  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($descriptions))
                  {
                     $des = $row['desc'];
                     echo '<option>'.$des.'</option>';
                  }
                  ?>
                  </select>
            </td>
        </tr>';
        <tr>
            <td>Description:<textarea rows="10" cols="10" name="desc" value="1"></textarea></td>
        </tr>     
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: No this isn't the mistake, Iamn't able to insert to database correctly

Comment: Then you'll need to do some debugging. mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: it was inserting but problem is it was inserting empty data in the column and when I type the description it was storing successfully

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes all over the place and you seem to miss starting and finishing PHP code:

```
echo '<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr><td>name:<input type="text" name="n"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Choose Desc
        <select name="desc" value="0">';

$descriptions = mysql_query('SELECT desc FROM desc_table');
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($descriptions))
    {
        $des = $row['desc'];
        echo '<option>'.$des.'</option>';
    }
    echo '
            </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description:<textarea rows="10" cols="10" name="desc" value="1"></textarea></td></tr>     
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>';
```

Comment: Ya the typing problem but my code was correct in my file but need help in inserting either one reason to database